# Problem with Desmos and almost rational number

Tags: irrational-numbers, constants

In finding almost rational number I have this :

Define :
$$f\left(x\right)=e^{x}-1-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{6}-\frac{x^{4}}{24}$$
$$h\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)+f\left(a\right)-f\left(x^{\frac{x}{x+a}}a^{\frac{a}{x+a}}-x-a\right)-f\left(\frac{xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)$$

Now consider for $a=2$:

$$h\left(35\right)-h\left(34\right)$$

My computer say that the result of this difference is $7.25$ and I think there is a miscalculations

Can someone tells me where is the mistake ?

If it's not an decimal number is it new ?

Comment: The computer is loosing precision due to the size of the numbers involved. That's an important disadvantage of floating point arithmetic, the default in most software. Using high precision arithmetic we get $h(35)-h(34) = 3.5571\ldots$

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks you very much for your light .

Comment: @jjagmath. The problem can be deeper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. Using Mathematica

`N[h(35)]` $=96.25$ $\qquad \qquad$ `N[h(34)]` $=89.$

`N[h(35),6]` $=97.2574$ $\qquad \qquad$ `N[h(34),6]` $=93.7003$

I thought that these two instrauction where the same

`N[Pi^Pi^Pi]` $=1.34016 \times 10^{18}$

`N[Pi^Pi^Pi,6]` $=1.34016 \times 10^{18}$